# How to use the value of a model in another value of the same django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model Group that has a field maximum_capacity and a member field, what i want to do is to use the value the user enters in the field maximum capacity to set the max_choices for the member field.

I am using Django2.2 and the max_choices option came from the MutiSelectField package i installed. I have tried converting to int using int() but gives the same error.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    number_of_group_members = ((i, i) for i in range(2, 100))
    members_choices = [(member.email, member.first_name + member.last_name)
                       for member in CustomUser.objects.all()]

    maximum_capacity = models.IntegerField(choices=number_of_group_members, 
        default='Specify group limit')
    members = MultiSelectField(max_choices=(i for i in 
        range(maximum_capacity)), unique=True, choices=members_choices)
```

I keep getting the Error:

```
members = MultiSelectField(max_choices=(i for i in range(maximum_capacity)),
TypeError: 'IntegerField' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `max_choices` is the maximum *number* of choices you can select. This is not a list, but a single number.

Comment: yes, maximium_capacity doesn't return a list

Comment: I am not talking about `maximum_capacity`, but the **`max_choices`** *parameter*. You can *not* pass a generator to that. It should be a (singular) sumber.

Comment: i am not clear on what you are trying to say, is it like a rule, like part of the docs?

Comment: @Fado the `members` field of the `Group` model has a generator passed to it as the `max_choices` parameter. This parameter should be an integer (number)

Comment: @Iain Shelvington okay , is there a way i can make max_choices == maximum_capacity

Answer (score 0):

One problem here may be be that your `IntegerField` default is a string value and that string could be causing trouble. Anyway, to help you properly you should post more code.

Comment: i tried changing the default to an integer it gave the same error. This is all the code that involves this problem, the views.py is just a simple API ListCreateAPIView.